# Ending a do while loop in C++ with a phony value

Tags: c++, do-while

I am having difficulty figuring out how to end a do-while loop in C++. I need to stop the loop after processing x amounts of data sets. That is, there is no set amount of data, the user determines when they are done entering in values.

I need to be able to stop my do-while loop when the user decided they're finished inputting data.

My main program is supposed to, in a loop, read in and process groups of 3 integer values until the end of the set of data.

For each group of the 3 values, the main program will print these and then send the 3 values as parameters to another function.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int temp1, temp2, temp3;

    do {
        cin >> temp1 >> temp2 >> temp3;
        cout << "The 3 values are: " << temp1 << " " << temp2 << " " << temp3 << endl;
    }
    while (****this is where I need help!*****);

    return 0;
}
```

My issue is that I have multiple input values, so how do I know what condition the while loop should have in order to stop processing values?

Comment: So *ask* the user "Do you want to continue?", and if not then exit the loop.

Comment: Forget about the code for a second. How do you want the program to behave, from the user's perspective?

Answer (score 1):

A simplest solution would be introducing a new input that based on value ( eg y or n) performs break operation

```
char temp4
std::cin>>temp4;

if(temp4!='y')
break; //exits the loop
```

or introduce the condition in

```
while(temp4=='y');
```

Comment: If I enter a `Y` the program quits.  Not what I was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it till EOF, you need `break`:

```
do {
    cin >> temp1 >> temp2 >> temp3;
    if (!cin)
        break;
    cout << "The 3 values are: " << temp1 << " " << temp2 << " " << temp3 << endl;
}
while (true);
```

or:

```
while (true) {
    cin >> temp1 >> temp2 >> temp3;
    if (!cin)
        break;
    cout << "The 3 values are: " << temp1 << " " << temp2 << " " << temp3 << endl;
}
```